# NSUrlConnection synchronous request without accepting redirects

Tags: macos, delphi, nsurlconnection, lazarus

I am currently implementing code that uses macOS API for HTTP/HTTPs requests in a Delphi/Lazarus program.

The code runs in its own thread (i.e. not main/ui thread) and is part of a larger threading based crawler across Windows/Mac and Delphi/Lazarus. I try to implement the actual HTTP/S request part using the OS API - but handle e.g. processing and taking action upon HTTP headers myself.

This means I would like to keep using synchronous mode if possible.

I want the request to simply return to me what the server returns.

I **do not want** it to follow redirects.

I currently use **sendSynchroniousRequest_returningResponse_error**

I have tried searching Google, but it seems there is no way when using synchronous requests? That just seems a bit odd.

Comment: [Ararat Synapse](https://sourceforge.net/projects/synalist/) is exactly for synchronous communication: http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/about

Comment: Thanks - but I already have implemented Indy as well - but I am trying to get out of OpenSSL dependency both Indy and Synapse have. The OpenSSL lib shipped with recent OSX versions do not work with websites using CloudFlare SSL certificates. (Yes, I could possibly distribute OpenSSL myself, but I rather not. Leaving it up to users to install OpenSSL is a nogo) - that is partly why I on Windows now also support WinInet/IE (latter for AJAX) and why I begun work on supporting HTTP/HTTPS through native Mac API.

Comment: Are you unable to use THTTPClient in Lazarus?

Comment: From THTTPClient only documentation states that that too requires OpenSSL to be distributed wih it / found on the system. The whole trouble is that the OpenSSL lib distribued with macOS is stating to be dated (albeit Apple been fairly good at patching it seems even if deprecated). My current macOS solution is Indy and use the OpenSSL already installed on the Mac system. As such it works well, but I am afraid this solution will soon stop working with many websites - and if that happens I have a big problem if I do not have a replacement ready.

Answer (score 1):

No, NSURLConnection's synchronous functionality is very limited, and was never expanded because it is so strongly discouraged.  That said, it is technically possible to implement what you're trying to do.

My recollection, from having replaced that method with an NSURLSession equivalent once (to swizzle in a less leaky replacement for that method in a binary-only library), is that you need to basically write a method that uses a shared dictionary to store a semaphore for each NSURLSessionDataTask (using the data task as a key).  Then, you set the semaphore's count to zero so that it will block immediately when you wait on it, asynchronously start an asynchronous request on the main thread, and then wait on the semaphore (in the current thread).  In the asynchronous data task's completion handler block, you increment the semaphore, thus unblocking the calling thread.

The trick is to ensure that the session runs its callbacks on a thread OTHER than the current one (which is blocked waiting for the semaphore).  So you'll need to dispatch_async into the main thread when you actually start the data task.

Ostensibly, if you supported converting the task into a download task or stream task in the relevant delegate method, you would also need to take appropriate action to update the shared dictionary as well, but I'm assuming you won't use that feature.  :-)

Comment: Upvoted and awarded bounty - not closing yet for the small hope of an answer that will solve my problems more easily. right now, I am trying to figure out how to use delegates in Lazarus "objective-pascal" - when that is solved I will move on along similar line like you describe. (Already begun work, delegate issue / time holding me back, but I believe that will be fully solved at some point.)

Comment: If blocks are easier, you could alternatively do the things I described above, but use the AFNetworking classes, which let you provide a block for handling redirects instead of a delegate method.